# Method for asking input easily not assigning input to variable

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to make a method to ask for input with a single line and assigning the input to a variable but it doesn't do so

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class MyClass {
  static void input(String inputprompt)
      System.out.print(inputprompt);
      Scanner userInput;
      userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = userInput.nextLine(); /* it is written as a new variable 
      because it generates an error otherwise*/ 
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) {
      String input = "useless for now"; /*this line is because it detects that there is no variable at 
      the line where it assigns the value of input to text before the script runs*/  
      input("what would you like the following text to be");
      String text = input; //the line refered to in previous comment
      System.out.print(text);
  }
}
```

It ends out saying "useless for now" regardless of what the input is which means it doesn't assign the variable (I think).

Comment: your method `input` should return the input .... but you return nothing and set only the variable input with the text `useless for now` ... this should help you https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/returnvalue.html

Comment: `input` is local to the method, so essentially you have two variables named "input". The one in main and the one in input. You could make a field named input at the class level.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to return your input statement in **input** method.

```
static String input(String inputprompt){

  System.out.print(inputprompt);
Scanner userInput;
userInput = new Scanner(System.in);
String input = userInput.nextLine();
return input;/* it is written as a new variable because it generates an
  error otherwise*/}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    String input = "useless for now"; /*this line is because it detects that there is no variable at
  the line where it assigns the value of input to text before the script runs*/
    String text = input("what would you like the following text to be");
    //the line refered to in previous comment
    System.out.print(text);
}
```

}